# I can screen share but not "connect"

Tags: macos

I have Mavericks installed on my iMac & Macbook. I cannot "connect" to my Macbook from my iMac but I can screenshare with no problem. I have the appropriate sharing boxes checked on both machines.

What is the issue?

Comment: by "connect" do you mean file share?

Comment: yes - where it's either/and "connect" or "share screen". It will share screen but not "connect" for the access to shared files that would be listed.

Answer (score 2):

Enable file share and make note of the address displayed.

To connect in file sharing follow [this instructions](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10644).

If your "connect" applies to control the other computer then enable the Remote Management.

Set the allowed user (or all)

Make a note of the "address" provided.

Start the Remote Desktop Connection app.

Enter the other computers information previously noted (on that computers remote settings).

It is something like the "Other users can manage your computer using the address 10.5.50.86"

Comment: Did all that except the remote management. I Know how to do that but shouldn't have to access that way - I know it's an option but I'd like to figure out why it won't connect (where I can see the shared folders, etc) the way it should.

Comment: On share files/folders you can only see the shared folder. To see all others you need remote access. Do you see the shared folder ??? Other users can access shared folders on this computer, and administrators all volumes, at .........

Comment: see my update in the answer